# Can basil flowers be substituted for basil leaves to make tea?

Tags: substitutions, food-science, basil

Can you use the basil flowers just like the leaves to make tea?

Comment: Ana, welcome to the site! Please note that health questions are off-topic here. I took the liberty to remove the part on effects on your body, otherwise we'd have to close this question.

Comment: Not really, but sort of.

See:http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/53953/how-can-one-use-thai-basil-stems-and-flowers/53971#53971

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use them the same way you would use the leaves- note that flowers are often used in herbal tea blends (I see hibiscus used particularly often). Depending on the cultivar, however, the flavor may be noticeably different than what you would get with the leaves, probably a bit more bitter- that's what I noticed when using mint flowers for tea, and mint is very closely related to basil.